# Как дописать бинарные данные в базу данных?

Tags: sql

Как дописать бинарные данные в базу данных?

Есть запись с бинарными данными. Как дописать в это поле данные. Чего-то я такого SQL запроса не встречал еще. Есть идеи?

Comment: Если дописать, то Update.

Answer (score 1):

Бинарные данные принято записывать в поле типа `BLOB`. В MySQL, например, так:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(id, blob_col) VALUES(1, LOAD_FILE('myfile.png')
```

Comment: Это понятно, как дописать-то?

Comment:     update MY_TABLE set blob_col = CONCAT(blob_col, <data>);